# Having trouble appending dictionary values to list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

[Dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HTcV.png) So in python I have a dictionary that is composed of a name for the key and a class object associated with the name as the object. I need to append these objects to a list one by one from the dictionary, however when I attempt to use a for loop to do so it only appends the same object over and over agian. When I try to append dict.values(), I have them appended to a list but with the word dict_values being the first thing in the list when it should only be the values themselves. Does anybody have any ideas as to how to properly append these values? I have been using

```
for value in playerDict.values():
    basicList.append(playerDict.values)
    print(basicList)
```

to try and append the values to the list called basicList, however every time it appends the same object and after a few iterations the list simply looks like

`[<built-in method values of dict object at 0x103a03d48>, <built-in method values of dict object at 0x103a03d48>, <built-in method values of dict object at 0x103a03d48>, <built-in method values of dict object at 0x103a03d48>]`

Where am I going wrong in appending the object values. Sorry for the basic question I am pretty new to python.

Comment: Add some codes to your question, error message or anything that will help other understand better what you want.

Comment: Just put some more information into the question

Comment: `basicList.append(value)`

Comment: That was embarrassingly easy, thanks though spectras

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
for value in playerDict.values():
    basicList.append(value)
    print(basicList)
```

Rather than:

```
for value in playerDict.values():
    basicList.append(playerDict.values)
    print(basicList)
```

When you try to append `playerDict.values` into the list, you were effectively trying to append value of the playerDict object in the object form and not what you stored in the key of the dictionary (and hence you were getting `[<built-in method values of dict object at 0x103a03d48>, <built-in method values of dict object at 0x103a03d48>`  ). Whereas, when you append `value`, it appends the actual values of the keys stored in your dictionary.

Hope, it helps.